# Ubuntu: Persisting IP Route Change on Reboot

Tags: ubuntu, ip, route

The following command at the terminal gives me the networking changes I need:

```
ip route change default via 10.255.255.1 dev eth0 src 82.82.82.82
```

To persist this on reboot I add the following to /etc/network/interfaces

```
post-up ip route change default via 10.255.255.1 dev eth0 src 82.82.82.82
```

After reboot the change is not applied - or is applied and subsequently overwritten - or something similar. How do I track down / debug why this is not working, as I am certain it should?

Alternatively, is there an other way I can apply the ip route change that will be effective?

Comment: Which distro are you using? Edit: forget it, couldn't read the title correctly. You could add a tag to Ubuntu, though.

Comment: Try with only `up` in /etc/network/interfaces, or write a script and save it in /etc/network/if-up.d/. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Really keen on a way to debug/see what is happening as my interfaces file works fine on my local network/VM, just not on this production server.

Comment: You could also try the "ugly" approach of using `/etc/rc.local` to add your route

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this line in /etc/network/interfaces

```
pre-down ip route change default via 10.255.255.1 dev eth0 src 82.82.82.82
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, can you share why you'd expect this to help? I'm afraid my knowledge is very thin in this area.

Comment: Based on the configuration of some of my virtual machines. I always have a pre-down and post-up and I have never had problems . I thought if I do not throw down the interface before restarting you may have problems because that interface stays caught. But... this don't solve your problem, right?

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't solve the problem. The Route Change is still either not being applied, or overwritten after it has been applied. Are there any logs to be checked?

Comment: Follow this link to turn over the logs and paste the result.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/230307/how-to-log-the-activity-of-a-network-interface-in-a-file

Answer (score -1):

The best answer I found was to add the command to a crontab. Clearly that's not a great solution. Would love to reliably be able to apply the change on boot.

Comment: Did you try the `/etc/rc.local` approach already mentioned by Lenniey?